# Can there be more than one servlet in a web project?

Tags: servlets

I am in the middle of creating a course registration system.

First, the user fills out a registration form and the user information is then stored in a DB. Then the user is sent to a login page. All of this is taken care of in a file named RegServlet.java.

On the next page, the user needs to enter the username and password in order to "log in" to see the list of courses offered.

Do I need to create another Servlet file? Tried to add another servlet to the web.xml file but had no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Tried to add another servlet to the web.xml file but had no luck.` Where is that ?

Comment: Of course there can be as many servlets as you like. Check out these popular tutorials: [Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be more than 1 servlet in a web project.

But, that is not what you are supposed to do in your case here. Ideally, you don't need to add another Servlet in the same web.xml file when you can isolate authentication and user registration.

For carrying out authentication please go through this [Java EE tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbwj.html)

Comment: In RegServlet class, I have a doGet() method that overrides the doStuff() method. doStuff() method takes the user input, connects to the DB, then stores the user input into the DB. How can I isolate authentication and user registration? Should I make another class for session management or just another method in RegServlet class?